# Typescript Support for JS Library (node-gtf) in a Express Project

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, gtfs

Have a Typescript Express Server for consuming GTFS data using the GTFS library (https://github.com/BlinkTagInc/node-gtfs)

- version ("gtfs": "^3.0.4")

Importing the library this way

`import { importGtfs } from 'gtfs';`

But due to no TS support I m facing this error

```
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of <Project-path>/node_modules/gtfs/index.js from <Project-path>/src/index.ts is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.
json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from <Project-path>/node_modules/gtfs/package.json.
```

Using it this way
`import { importGtfs } from 'gtfs';`

Found a type Library for GTFS
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gtfs-types
But unable to  find a solution to include these types in the Project

Comment: which version of gtfs are you using?

Comment: @deechris27 "gtfs": "^3.0.4"

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the "type": "module" property in package.json of the gtfs version you're using

[image]

type = module would expect es6 syntax however somewhere commonjs require is used.

this is a known issue with node v12.11.0 which was resolved in v12.11.1

you could downgrade the gtfs version to 2.4.4 which doesn't have this type:module property.

If this is a dependency of dependency then add it to resolutions

```
"resolutions":{
   "gtfs": "^2.4.4"
}
```

Comment: Are there any major difference between versions 2.4.x and 3.0.x ?

Comment: I compared the two releases and there was no difference.

https://github.com/BlinkTagInc/node-gtfs/compare/3.0.4...2.4.4