# SSR with React : Unexpected token '<' in call to renderToString()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I'm working on SSR with react but I'm encountering the following error.
**Syntax error: Unexpected token '<'`**

````
 <div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>```
                                                ^
````

As mentioned is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961697/react-express-unexpected-token-in-call-to-rendertostring/44961979)

> `babel-register` doesn't process the file it is called from.

Therefore, I rightly declared my `babel` dependencies in a new file, however I'm still getting the above error.

Below is my `index.js` file

```
import babelRegister from '@babel/register';
import ignoreStyles from 'ignore-styles';

babelRegister({
  ignore: [/node_modules/],
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
});

import express from 'express';
import appRender from './server.js';

const app = express();
appRender(app);
```

My `server.js` file.

```
import initialRenderRoutes from './routes/initialRenderRoutes.js';
import path from 'path';

const appRender = (app) => {
  const __dirname = path.resolve();

  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')));

  app.use('*', initialRenderRoutes);

  const port = 5000;

  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
};
export default appRender;
```

My `initialController.js` file

```
import fs from 'fs';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server.js';
import path from 'path';

import App from '../../src/App.js';

const initialRenderController = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(path.resolve());
  fs.readFile(
    path.resolve('../client/build/index.html'),
    'utf8',
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      }
      return res.send(
        data.replace(
          '<div id="root"></div>',
          `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>`
              <<<<The problem lies here>>>>
        )
      );
    }
  );
};

export default initialRenderController;
```

**Is it something related to babel, please help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below changes in your `index.js` file,

```
require('ignore-styles');

require('@babel/register')({
    ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
});

require('./server');
require('./initialController');
```

The above should work, I tested locally the below, it works perfectly fine.

My `server.js`

```
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

import App from '../App';

const app = express();

app.use('^/$', (req, res, next) => {

    fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send("Some error occurred")
        }
        return res.send(data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>`))
    })
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build")));

app.listen(5000, ()=>{
    console.log("App running on port 5k")
})
```

index.js

```
require('ignore-styles');

require('@babel/register')({
    ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
});

require('./server');
```

I hope you have the .babelrc file with the required presets.

**Update in response to comment:**

Consider removing `type: "module"`, since it will throw error when you use `require`. `@babel/register` will run files using babel on the **fly**. The require hook will bind itself to the node’s require and will automatically compile files at **runtime**. `server.js` using es module won't clash if you remove `type: "module"`. The order of `require` matters, we require babel-register in `index.js` with the presets needed to recognize the syntaxes in the *then-required* server.js.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. As mentioned I made changes to my `index.js` file and converted it to `require` syntax. It worked but now the styles do not get rendered from the server. Also, can you tell me why you shifted to a `require` syntax for `index.js` file and why not `ES module` syntax work considered that I'm adding `type : "module"` in my `package.json` file. 
One more thing is in `index.js` file with `require('./server')` at the last line, the `server.js` uses `es module` syntax for importing/exporting won't it **clash** with `require` syntax in `index.js` file.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an explanation.

Comment: I understood how babel presets would recognize syntax in the `server.js` file and therefore this won't **clash** with the `require` syntax in `index.js` file, thank you for clearing this out.
However, writing `type : "module"` allows us to use `es module syntax` in our node files. So can't we make our `index.js` to use `es module syntax`? Those `require` syntax in `index.js`, can we change it to `es module` syntax?

Comment: Yes, I understand, I suggested require bcoz I don't know the version of node you have in system, I believe it'll only work for node above version 12. it's safer to recommend require since it will work for everyone unless they've "type":"module" or .mjs files. Yes, you can try with es-modules in index.js, personally, I haven't tried so far.

Comment: @TarunSingh if my answer helped with your issue, please consider accepting, upvoting. Thanks

Comment: Okay got it, also can you please edit your answer as it mentions that removing `type: module` will throw an error when using `require` syntax, I think it's the other way round. If you put `type:module` then it'll throw an error saying `require` is not defined. So if we're using `require` syntax then we don't need to add `type: module` in our `package.json` file.

Comment: I'd figured out the issue with this "type:module" while I tried to debug for this issue (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68210160/8370370) sometime back. I've edited that part of answer so that It's not confusing :). I actually meant to say using require with type:module will throw error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two things that need to be changed. One on your **initialControler.js** you are using export default in a node.js file, use module.exports
[module.exports vs. export default in Node.js and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6)

You should change all the imports in your node files.

You use export / export default in React and then import to pull in the files
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-importing-exporting/

module.exports and require to pull in the files for Node
[What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it?rq=1)

Second they moved the app.get into that **renderReact.js** file and then required it into their **index.js** file. However on your **server.js** file I don't see you importing in your initialController file.

From your example it looks like you should be doing something like this:

**Server.js**

```
let initialController = require('/path to this file');
initialController(app)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The latest version of node does support `es module syntax`. I've accepted the other answer. Thank you for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yow broh don’t waste yow time reading them parchments.
All you need to do is remove any space b4 and after each `><`

```
const val= ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);

/// make sure you don’t have any sort of space 
/// between them > < and yow ${}
/// is better if you store that long  text into an small var, as I did to ///prevent prettier or some other  to add a line break of an space

return res.send( `<div id="root">${val}</div>`);
```